# SQL request to find if a period is fully covered

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sum

I have a set of periods like:

```
CREATE TABLE `periods` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_at` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_at` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOCK TABLES `periods` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `periods` (`id`, `start_at`, `end_at`)
VALUES
    (1,'2013-04-29','2013-04-30'),
    (2,'2013-05-05','2013-05-10'),
    (3,'2013-05-10','2013-05-15'),
    (4,'2013-05-15','2013-05-16'),
    (5,'2013-05-18','2013-05-19'),
    (6,'2013-05-19','2013-05-25');

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

My intended desire, is the most optimized way to know if a given period is fully covered by one or multiple periods.

For instance:

1) to get `null` for a request from `2013-04-29` until `2013-05-10`, cause no period covers from `2013-04=30` to `2013-05-05`

2) to get the period ids (or at least `true` or any content) for a request from `2013-05-06` to `2013-05-15`

UPDATE: The main goal is to define if the given period (from `2013-05-06` to `2013-05-15` as per example 2) is rentable. The periods in database are available rental seasons, so if any of the day are not covered, the entire stay can not be rented.

Comment: Are periods unique and non-overlapping?

Comment: @Aushin yes, periods are unique and never overlaps.

Comment: not a solution but a direction:  you need 3 checks - 1. the start date falls within an existing range. 2. the end date falls within an existing range. 3. the difference between the start date and the end of the range + the difference between the end date and the beginning of its range is >= the end date - start date.

Comment: meh - for my above comment, you will need to coalesce any contiguous ranges...

Comment: Are you start and end dates supposed to be inclusive or exclusive? For example, is 2013-05-10 supposed to be covered by period 2 or period 3?

Comment: @vincebowdren the start_at is inclusive and end_at exclusive

Comment: So, really you're looking for any date NOT covered by the above!

Comment: @Strawberry No, I'm looking to know if it's entirely covered

Comment: @Strawberry just added further details to better explain the real usage.

Comment: @SébastienGrosjean-ZenCocoon I think my way may be a simpler way of stating the same thing! I'll read through your amendments, but in the meantime can you clarify what you think the 'uncovered' or 'available' periods are in your example. For instance, are there two periods (4/30-5/5 & 5/10-5/18) or are there more?

Comment: @SébastienGrosjean-ZenCocoon Did you resolve this? I think the answer I gave should work without too much tweaking.

Answer (score 2):

### **EDIT:** See here for a MySQL working SQL Fiddle: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b3c2/47), that actually works properly this time :-)

Try these. The bottom line is that if `Shortfall > 0` then you can't book the rental.

**MSSQL** - this is how I worked it out

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME = '2013-04-29' -- this will depend on your dateformat
DECLARE @end DATETIME = '2013-05-10'
DECLARE @days INT = DATEDIFF(D,@start, @end) -- this is how many days we actually want to stay
DECLARE @unusedDays INT = 0 -- this will be the number of unused days from the rental periods in which our start and end dates fall
SELECT  @UnusedDays = DATEDIFF(D,@end,end_at) FROM PERIODS WHERE (@end > start_at AND @end <= end_at) -- how many spare days are there in the final period?
SELECT  @UnusedDays = @UnusedDays + DATEDIFF(D,start_at, @start) FROM PERIODS WHERE (@start >= start_at AND @start < end_at) -- how many spare days are there in the start period?
SELECT  @days + @UnusedDays - SUM(DATEDIFF(D,start_at,end_at)) AS Shortfall, -- total shortfall in days. Zero if we are okay to rent
        SUM(DATEDIFF(D,start_at,end_at)) AS AvailableDays, -- total number of days available in all periods covering our chosen rental period
        @days AS DesiredDays, -- number of days we want to rent
        @UnusedDays AS WastedDays -- number of wasted days (if we start or end our rental mid-period)
FROM    PERIODS 
WHERE   (@start >= start_at AND @start < end_at) -- period in which our selected rental starts
OR      (end_at < @end AND start_at > @start) -- period completely within our selected rental
OR      (@end > start_at AND @end <= end_at) -- period in which our selected rental ends
```

This provides output like this:

```
-- if you have @start = '2013-05-05'
-- and @end = '2013-05-13'
-- then you get
Shortfall AvailableDays DesiredDays WastedDays

0---------10------------8-----------2---------

-- if you have @start = '2013-04-29'
-- and @end = '2013-05-10'
-- then you get
Shortfall AvailableDays DesiredDays WastedDays

5---------6-------------11----------0---------
```

**MySQL** - this is what you actually want

```
SET @start = '2013-04-29';
SET @end = '2013-05-10';
SET @days = DATEDIFF(@end, @start); -- this is how many days we actually want to stay
SET @UnusedDays = 0; -- this will be the number of unused days from the rental periods in which our start and end dates fall
SELECT  @UnusedDays := DATEDIFF(end_at,@end) FROM PERIODS WHERE (@end > start_at AND @end <= end_at); -- how many spare days are there in the final period?
SELECT 'hello';
SELECT  @UnusedDays := @UnusedDays + DATEDIFF(@start, start_at) FROM PERIODS WHERE (@start >= start_at AND @start < end_at); -- how many spare days are there in the start period?
SELECT 'hello';
SELECT  @days + @UnusedDays - SUM(DATEDIFF(end_at, start_at)) AS Shortfall, -- total shortfall in days. Zero if we are okay to rent
        SUM(DATEDIFF(end_at, start_at)) AS AvailableDays, -- total number of days available in all periods covering our chosen rental period
        @days AS DesiredDays, -- number of days we want to rent
        @UnusedDays AS WastedDays -- number of wasted days (if we start or end our rental mid-period)
FROM    PERIODS 
WHERE   (@start >= start_at AND @start < end_at) -- period in which our selected rental starts
OR      (end_at < @end AND start_at > @start) -- period completely within our selected rental
OR      (@end > start_at AND @end <= end_at); -- period in which our selected rental ends
```

Comment: I don't think it's quite working; if I try a date range of 2013-05-06 to 2013-05-17, that's not rentable because none of the periods include 2013-05-17 - but your SQLFiddle demo says there's a shortfall of 0, implying that the range is rentable.

Comment: It works for the SQL Server version. I guess I messed up when I was converting it to MySQL...

Comment: SQLFiddle just died, so I can't update the fiddle, or even test this, but I think you need to change the bits that start like this `SELECT  @UnusedDays = ...` to be like this `SELECT  @UnusedDays := ...`. Note the added `:`.

Comment: All now fixed. My suspicions about the `:` were correct and this now works the same as the MSSQL version. Thanks for the heads up @vincebowdren :-)

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While I like the approach of @Dommer and the details included (thanks a lot for that) I prefer the approach contributed by @snoyes on IRC#mysql.

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*), false, true) AS rentable
FROM(
  SELECT
    a.end_at AS START,
    Min(b.start_at) AS END
  FROM periods AS a
  JOIN periods AS b ON a.end_at <= b.start_at
  GROUP BY a.end_at
  HAVING a.end_at < MIN(b.start_at)
) AS gaps
WHERE
  gaps.START < '2013-05-17' AND gaps.END > '2013-05-05';
```

A working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/134a0/22) is also available.

For more details, the initial reference comes from http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=577

Comment: That's pretty cool! Although running it in MSSQL (I removed the IF bit that is MySQL specific) against my MSSQL version, the query plan says mine is twice as efficient.

Comment: That's interesting about the query plan. Thanks a lot for sharing.

Comment: This solution is actually having some issues, some dates are considered rentable when they should not: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/134a0/30

Comment: Hmmm. You know my solutions works with those dates, don't you? Although you do need to get the dates in the right order with mine (trivial to do).

Comment: Hi @Dommer, I'm actually trying to implement your solution in Rails and face a few issues described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715237/translate-complex-sql-query-using-set-to-arel-or-squeel?noredirect=1#comment24064086_16715237 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715064/using-datediff-in-select-with-squeel . What do you mean by "you do need to get the dates in the right order"?

Comment: I just meant that in my example code the date `@start` has to be the earlier date and `@end` has to be the later date. I'll have a look at your questions in a bit, but I've never used Rails...

Comment: ok, that felt obvious but thanks a lot for the precision. What do you think about the approach proposed by @Gordon Linoff? My problem with Rails seems to be relative to SET and DATEDIFF, they might be ways around but still can't figure them out.

Comment: I think I'd put my original answer into a stored procedure which reads from the periods table and into which you just pass start date, end date and probably propertyId or whatever, so it gets the correct periods.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ID from `periods`
where
    start_at >= <Your_given_start> 
    and end_at <= <Your_given_end>
```

This unfortunately only returns something, if there is a period covered.

Comment: sadly, this won't work over multiple periods and it's what I am looking for. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in one query.  The following query assumes that you have `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` defined.

The key idea is that you only need to test for one day before a start date or one day after an end date.  If there is a period with no coverage, then it will appear during this time.  The following query calculates the test dates and whether they are aavailable:

```
select TestDay, COUNT(p.id)     
from ((select p.Start_at - 1 as TestDay
       from #Periods p
       where p.start_at > @StartDate and p.start_at <= @EndDate
      )
      union all
      (select p.End_at
       from #periods p
       where p.start_at >= @StartDate and p.start_at < @EndDate
      )
     ) t left outer join
     #periods p
     on t.TestDay >= p.start_at and t.TestDay < p.end_at
group by TestDay;
```

This is more information than you need.  You just want `0` in the first case and `1` in the second case.  This is just a test of whether `p.id` in the above query is ever `NULL`:

```
select MAX(case when p.id is null then 1 else 0 end)  
from ((select p.Start_at - 1 as TestDay
       from #Periods p
       where p.start_at > @StartDate and p.start_at <= @EndDate
      )
      union all
      (select p.End_at
       from #periods p
       where p.start_at >= @StartDate and p.start_at < @EndDate
      )
     ) t left outer join
     #periods p
     on t.TestDay >= p.start_at and t.TestDay < p.end_at;
```

This query might have an off-by-one error (depending on whether there is availability on the end date).  Such a problem is easily fixed.

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work in sqlfiddle but still face few issues : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/134a0/38 :( Feeling really noob here